# Win32 - separating data in multiple loaded DLL instances in pure C

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, dll, ipc

I know this topic is often asked, but I found no answers for C.
I can't use C++ for several compatibility issues (crossplatform compiling).
So I had to rewrite engine in C. The engine itself uses Lua and several global variables (I know global is evil).

Engine is used by closed source program (single threaded) as DLL plugin. The problem occurs when the program uses multiple engine clones. It is all the same DLL loaded several times. The question is what is best approach if I can't use C++?

I think about placing global data in some kind of struct-table and access it via macros according to unique ID. But how can I identify DLL instances for sure in Win32?
Of may be there are another patterns?

Comment: So you have multiple plugins loaded simultaneously, and they all load the same DLL which uses global data? Are they all loaded on the same thread?

Comment: One simple if inelegant option is to make multiple copies of the DLL.  Windows doesn't attempt to de-duplicate DLLs, if they have different names (or are in different directories and the complete path is provided when the DLL is loaded) they are treated as different entities.

Comment: You mean: if the same program loads your DLL twice, how can you distinguish the two loaded DLLs?

Comment: (the answer to that is that you can't load a DLL twice)

Comment: Yes, the DLL is loaded to the same thread. DLL can be renamed, I know it. But it will broke the whole idea. Each DLL is one device. You can use many similar devices in simulation. I need to find out, where I am exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-designed plugin system must not require plugins for having any global variables. Common C-style Plugin API design looks like

```
ObjectHandle CreateObject(...);
ReturnType CallSomeMethod(ObjectHandle handle, ...);
```

In CreateObject you allocate a structure (e.g. MyObject) with all data required and return pointer to MyObject. In CallSomeMethod you cast handle to MyObject* and obtain your data.

If plugin system you deal with is well-designed, just follow this rule. 
If it is not, then throw it away or clone your DLL as adviced above. 
By the way, the language (C, C++) doesn't matter here at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fact I decided to extend virtual table, as I emulated program classes and include all my data in it